# SSDT unresolved references

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

How can I correctly work with a database in SSDT when that database has a role that other users in the SQL Server are included into?

For example, say I have one database called "Shared", and 120 other databases whose SQL login accounts are included into the "LookupName" DB Role in "Shared".

I don't mind if SSDT wants ensure that the "LookupName" DB role exists.  However, I don't want it to try to create all 120 users that happen to be in that role!  But if try to exclude them, I get other errors.

The structure of the "Shared" database is not affected by how many users may be in a role... that is something the DBA needs to be able to set as needed. So how can I ensure that SSDT does not include them in a comparison?

SSDT Comparison has 110+ check boxes for things to include, ignore, etc. etc., but I haven't been able to find the ones I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do, and what actually happens. SSDT has many components, and I'm not able to work out what tools you're using and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools) has a settings button that enables the comparison to exclude certain features.

So, excluding "Role Memberships" and "Users" under the "Object Types" / "Application - Scoped" solved the issue.